# Did Blender have modifier Edit Poly(3dsmax) in the lastest version Blender_3.3.1

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Did Blender have modifier Edit Poly(3dsmax) at lastest version Blender_3.3.1.
I search on google but the last result was 2 years ago. Did anyone know new update have it ?

Comment: Blender never had an *Edit Poly* modifier, now nor years ago

Comment: I wish it had one.... It's been requested on RCS for a long time https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/y9ZW/?sorting=new&page=1&text=etit+modifier#

Answer (score 0):

Editing mesh elements is not considered a modifier in Blender. If you have a Mesh(poly) object in Blender you can just hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to enter edit mode and edit its elements like vertices (<kbd>1</kbd>), edges (<kbd>2</kbd>) and faces (<kbd>3</kbd>).

This is very basic functionality so if you want to learn stuff like this, it might be way more efficient to watch a few beginner tutorials like these official ones: https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/ instead of asking questions here. Obviously, you can find plenty other good ones. Don't get me wrong - if you have a question about Blender, this is the place for it, it's just that it will most likely be faster and easier to get the basic stuff out of the way with video tutorials.

If you want to know about modifiers in Blender, they are all located here in the Modifier Tab in the Properties Editor:

[image]

You can find explanations for each one in the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/index.html)